# Outputs from two decorators issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

Please help to understand how I can receive outputs from two decorators.
It's my code :

```
def check1(function1):

  def getver1():
    ver1 = 0.1
    return getattr(function1(ver1))

  return getver1()


def check2(function2):

  def getver2():
    ver2 = 0.2
    return getattr(function2(ver2))

  return getver2()

@check1
@check1
class ClassObj(object):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
```

And from this, Im receiving only output from second one, but why?

> ('0.2')

Comment: Your two decorators each seem to be calling their inner function instead of returning them. check1 should end with return getver1

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to edit your code. There's quite a few bugs, and you use `check1` twice without using `check2`. There is no way you are seeing an output of `('0.2')` with your current code.

Also, You're using class decorators in the wrong way. A good reference is this article: https://krzysztofzuraw.com/blog/2016/python-class-decorators.html

Answer (score 0):

Decorators stack from top to bottom. Code like

```
@check1
@check2
class ClassObj(object):
    ...
```

is equivalent to

```
class ClassObj(object):
    ...

ClassObj = check1(check2(ClassObj))
```

that is, you decorate `ClassObj` with `check1`, then decorate the result with `check2`.

The problem you are having, though, is that neither of your decorators actually returns a class. They both make (incorrect) calls to `getattr` with an *instance* of the given class.

Comment: Yes, but even a correct call to `getattr` isn't likely to produce a value suitable for the decorator to return.

Comment: We're a long way from a decorator. But how does the OP get the claimed output when there are several things wrong before getting to `print(args)`?

Comment: @quamrana No idea, and I'm not particularly interested. There's really too much wrong with the code to do anything other than point out how decorators are supposed to work.